# Acces my ssh server from one of my internal LAN

Tags: ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

I have attached a picture with my logical scheme of my network to understand better what I'm trying to say. 
I have 2 routers, one it's from my ISP, let's say R1, and the second one it's a laptop with ubuntu, let's say R2 (it has two network cards). The network between two routers is 192.168.1.0/29, R1 has ip 192.168.1.1 and R2 has 192.168.1.2 (interface eth0). The second interface (eth 1) has ip 192.168.0.1 (network 192.168.0.0/24). The dhcp range for the other computers is 192.168.0.100-110.
My ssh server is on the laptop and it's listening to ip 192.168.0.1, port 1234.
My configuration of my iptable is:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [16767:7976143]
:INPUT ACCEPT [8821:5501124]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7946:2475019]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7365:959690]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [14882:3396630]
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [267:20644]
:INPUT ACCEPT [5:808]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [205:14321]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [94:5989]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:1234
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1651:250417]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234-j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

If I'm trying to access my server from outside (public ip) everything it's working well. If I'm trying to access my server from my LAN 192.168.0.0/24 everything it's working well
But if I'm trying to access my server from my LAN 192.168.1.0/29, doesn't work and i don't know what I'm missing.

My sysctl.conf file

```
# Uncomment this to allow this host to route packets between interfaces
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding=1
#net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1
#net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1

# Disable ICMP redirects. ICMP redirects are rarely used but can be used in
# MITM (man-in-the-middle) attacks. Disabling ICMP may disrupt legitimate
# traffic to those sites.
net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_redirects=0

# Ignore bogus ICMP errors
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=0

# Don't log Martian Packets (impossible addresses)
# packets
net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians=0
net/ipv4/conf/default/log_martians=0
```

ip route command:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.1.0/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
```

sudo lsof -i :1234 -sTCP:LISTEN

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    870 root    3u  IPv4  26434      0t0  TCP router:1234 (LISTEN)
```

I'm newbie in network and linux, it's a hobby :)

[image: logical scheme of my network]

New output from iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun May  3 12:14:53 2020
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [71:7480]
:logdrop - [0:0]
-A logdrop -j LOG
-A logdrop -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May  3 12:14:53 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun May  3 12:14:53 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1086:123572]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:313]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [103:7764]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [45:3406]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May  3 12:14:53 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun May  3 12:14:53 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8337:3369260]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1900:1013491]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6432:2355533]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1667:164865]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8160:2526231]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May  3 12:14:53 2020
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. What are the routes (`ip route` output)? Do you have forwarding enabled for IPv4?

Comment: I do not know that you can do what you are trying to. It doesn't work for all interfaces to forward stuff out and in via the same spot. However, I am not certain. Regardless, I would alllow my SSH server to also listen on 192.168.1.2

Comment: @DougSmythies standard for SSH would be to listen on all interfaces. But since the OP evidently changed the port to non-standard (which I find _highly_ questionable, especially since it's a port in a range to which unprivileged processes are allowed to bind as well), it's a fair point. `lsof -i :1234` (or more specifically `lsof -i :1234 -sTCP:LISTEN` would show (`netstat` and `ss` would be alternatives).

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yes, i have enabled forwarding in /etc/ufw/sysctl. My ip route is default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.1.0/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2

Comment: @Alex could you please edit that into your question. It's hard to read something like that without _some_ formatting. Could you add the output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` for completeness and the output of one of the suggested `lsof` commands, please?!

Comment: @DougSmythies,  I thought about that too

Comment: @0xC0000022L, I didn't choose port 1234, i have modified the post. I chose a port number from those that are not reserved (49152-65535).

Comment: @Alex this doesn't make it any better in regard to my point, though (an unprivileged user could deny service _or_ spoof it - although the latter is harder and depends on human nature to ignore the explicit warnings from SSH clients). Either way, the output from `lsof` suggests SSH is only listening on one IP (`router`, so I presume `192.168.1.1`?). I'd suggest to sprinkle a few `-j LOG` rules between the existing ones and see what turns up in the logs. Is there a specific reason why SSH can't simply listen on both interfaces in the first place?

Comment: @0xC0000022L, I thought it's more safe to be behind from second router. :). Yes, SSH is only listening to ip 192.168.0.1. I don't know where to put _-j LOG_

Comment: i checked now and even if i leave the server to listen to the both interfaces , still i can't access my server from LAN 192.168.1.0/29

Comment: When you set it to listen on both interfaces, did you also delete those iptables rules? It will not work with those rules as the packets will not get to the SSH server daemon.

Comment: @Alex see [here](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-3.html#ss3.14). Simply pipe the output of `iptables-save` to some file, edit the file (as per the link) and then load the new rules by using that file with `iptables-restore`.

Comment: @DougSmythies, I have deleted those rules and still doesn't work. I put new output of my iptables in my question

Comment: @0xC0000022L, i added those line in my rules.v4 (I'm using iptables persistent). But i don't know where is the log file. I looked in kern.log file but nothing. So i added in _/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf_ file one line to log my kernel.warning in _/var/log/iptables.log_ I also issue the command: _iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.1 -j LOG --log-level 4_  but nothing

Comment: The log entries should have gone to `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` by default. What version of Ubuntu? Depending on your version, do this `sudo netstat -tlnp` or `sudo ss -tlnp` and edit into your question. Do the command when (you think) your `sshd` is listening to eth0.